# Filling out a select tag with requests Python

Tags: python, html, select, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to choose/enter a value to a select tag using Python Requests
For some reason, this doesn't work

Html code:

```html
<select name="hourly_rate" class="default-input" id="hourly_rate">
                            <option value="0" id="dafault_hourly_rate" selected="">Any hourly rate</option>
                            <option value="10"> &lt; $10/hour</option>
                            <option value="10-20"> $10-20/hour</option>
                            <option value="20-30"> $20-30/hour</option>
                            <option value="30-40"> $30-40/hour</option>
                            <option value="40"> &gt; $40/hour</option>
                        </select>
```

Python code:

```
  data = {
  'name' : 'hourly-rate',
  'value' : '10-20',
}

sauce = requests.post(urlis,data=data)
sauce = sauce.content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct data structure at all. You need a key-value pair:

```
data = {
   'hourly-rate': '10-20',
}
```

Comment: @FilipLavMaksimovic it should work, unless there are more post fields in the page.