# How to scrape from website with multiple 'select' field?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I wish to scrape weather of the entire December 2018 from  https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/new-york/historic?month=12&year=2018

This web page has 2 selections fields. I am completely new to html and post requests. I have read the answers from [Filling out a select tag with requests Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701493/filling-out-a-select-tag-with-requests-python) .It seems to me that I need to include all field id-value pair. Below is my code.

```
import requests
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/new-york/historic?month=12&year=2018",
    data={
        "month": r'2018-12',
        "wt-his-select": r"20181205",
    })
```

I expect weather records of the fifth of December 2018 according to the id-value pair I entered above, but instead I am always getting weather of 1st of December

Comment: please have a look at python's beautiful soup library for pulling data. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you please be a little more specific? I can't find the related method or function from the bs4 documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Us beautifulsoup to pull out the `<script>` tags, as the data is there in a json format. Then read that into a dictionary to convert to dataframe:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/new-york/historic?month=12&year=2018")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'var data=' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('var data=')[-1].split(';window.')[0]

        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

weather = jsonData['detail']
results = pd.DataFrame()
for each in weather:
    results = results.append(pd.DataFrame([each]), sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
      baro          date                        desc  ...     ts wd wind
0    30.14  1.543622e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
1    30.21  1.543644e+12                      Sunny.  ...   6 am  0    0
2    30.17  1.543666e+12                      Sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
3    30.13  1.543687e+12       Light rain. Overcast.  ...   6 pm  0    0
4    29.96  1.543709e+12            Light rain. Fog.  ...  12 am  0    0
5    29.80  1.543730e+12            Light rain. Fog.  ...   6 am  0    0
6    29.65  1.543752e+12                        Fog.  ...  12 pm  0    0
7    29.62  1.543774e+12                        Fog.  ...   6 pm  0    0
8    29.58  1.543795e+12             Passing clouds.  ...  12 am  0    0
9    29.63  1.543817e+12                      Sunny.  ...   6 am  0    0
10   29.66  1.543838e+12                   Overcast.  ...  12 pm  0    0
11   29.72  1.543860e+12                      Clear.  ...   6 pm  0    0
12   29.80  1.543882e+12                   Overcast.  ...  12 am  0    0
13   29.93  1.543903e+12                   Overcast.  ...   6 am  0    0
14   29.96  1.543925e+12                      Sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
15   30.06  1.543946e+12                      Clear.  ...   6 pm  0    0
16   30.08  1.543968e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
17   30.09  1.543990e+12                      Sunny.  ...   6 am  0    0
18   30.03  1.544011e+12                      Sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
19   30.09  1.544033e+12                      Clear.  ...   6 pm  0    0
20   30.14  1.544054e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
21   30.19  1.544076e+12                      Sunny.  ...   6 am  0    0
22   30.15  1.544098e+12                      Sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
23   30.14  1.544119e+12              Mostly cloudy.  ...   6 pm  0    0
24   30.18  1.544141e+12             Passing clouds.  ...  12 am  0    0
25   30.32  1.544162e+12                      Sunny.  ...   6 am  0    0
26   30.34  1.544184e+12                      Sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
27   30.44  1.544206e+12                      Clear.  ...   6 pm  0    0
28   30.45  1.544227e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
29   30.48  1.544249e+12             Passing clouds.  ...   6 am  0    0
..     ...           ...                         ...  ...    ... ..  ...
94   30.03  1.545653e+12               Partly sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
95   30.09  1.545674e+12                      Clear.  ...   6 pm  0    0
96   30.17  1.545696e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
97   30.26  1.545718e+12                   Overcast.  ...   6 am  0    0
98   30.27  1.545739e+12                      Sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
99   30.34  1.545761e+12                      Clear.  ...   6 pm  0    0
100  30.40  1.545782e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
101  30.47  1.545804e+12                   Overcast.  ...   6 am  0    0
102  30.43  1.545826e+12               Partly sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
103  30.47  1.545847e+12                      Clear.  ...   6 pm  0    0
104  30.52  1.545869e+12                   Overcast.  ...  12 am  0    0
105  30.60  1.545890e+12                      Sunny.  ...   6 am  0    0
106  30.56  1.545912e+12                      Sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
107  30.51  1.545934e+12                   Overcast.  ...   6 pm  0    0
108  30.34  1.545955e+12            Light rain. Fog.  ...  12 am  0    0
109  30.14  1.545977e+12                  Rain. Fog.  ...   6 am  0    0
110  29.91  1.545998e+12            Light rain. Fog.  ...  12 pm  0    0
111  29.83  1.546020e+12                        Fog.  ...   6 pm  0    0
112  29.85  1.546042e+12              Mostly cloudy.  ...  12 am  0    0
113  29.97  1.546063e+12           Scattered clouds.  ...   6 am  0    0
114  30.07  1.546085e+12               Partly sunny.  ...  12 pm  0    0
115  30.16  1.546106e+12                   Overcast.  ...   6 pm  0    0
116  30.17  1.546128e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
117  30.23  1.546150e+12       Light snow. Overcast.  ...   6 am  0    0
118  30.21  1.546171e+12                   Overcast.  ...  12 pm  0    0
119  30.27  1.546193e+12              Mostly cloudy.  ...   6 pm  0    0
120  30.30  1.546214e+12                      Clear.  ...  12 am  0    0
121  30.34  1.546236e+12                   Overcast.  ...   6 am  0    0
122  30.23  1.546258e+12  Light rain. Mostly cloudy.  ...  12 pm  0    0
123  30.00  1.546279e+12            Heavy rain. Fog.  ...   6 pm  0    0

[124 rows x 14 columns]
```

**ADDITIONAL:**

You can get individual days (hour by hour) by accessing the json. Just change the parameters in the `payload` to get a specific date:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/cityajax.php'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}

year = 2018
month = 12
day = 1

payload = {
'n': 'usa/new-york',
'mode': 'historic',
'hd': '%d%02d%02d' %(year, month, day),
'month': '%02d' %(month),
'year': '%d' %(year)}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).text
table = pd.read_html('<table>' + data + '</table>')[0][:-1]
table = table.dropna(axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (table.to_string())
    Unnamed: 0_level_0 Conditions                                        Comfort          Unnamed: 7_level_0 Unnamed: 8_level_0
                  Time       Temp                     Weather Unnamed: 5_level_1 Humidity          Barometer         Visibility
0   12:51 amSat, Dec 1      40 °F                   Overcast.                  ↑      80%          30.11 "Hg              10 mi
1              1:51 am      40 °F             Passing clouds.                  ↑      77%          30.12 "Hg              10 mi
2              2:51 am      39 °F                      Clear.                  ↑      79%          30.12 "Hg              10 mi
3              3:51 am      39 °F                      Clear.                  ↑      79%          30.13 "Hg              10 mi
4              4:51 am      38 °F             Passing clouds.                  ↑      79%          30.16 "Hg              10 mi
5              5:51 am      37 °F                      Clear.                  ↑      82%          30.17 "Hg               9 mi
6              6:51 am      37 °F                      Clear.                  ↑      86%          30.19 "Hg              10 mi
7              7:51 am      38 °F                      Sunny.                  ↑      79%          30.21 "Hg              10 mi
8              8:51 am      40 °F                      Sunny.                  ↑      73%          30.21 "Hg              10 mi
9              9:51 am      42 °F                      Sunny.                  ↑      68%          30.22 "Hg              10 mi
10            10:51 am      44 °F           Scattered clouds.                  ↑      63%          30.21 "Hg              10 mi
11            11:51 am      44 °F                      Sunny.                  ↑      60%          30.21 "Hg              10 mi
12            12:51 pm      45 °F                      Sunny.                  ↑      58%          30.18 "Hg              10 mi
13             1:51 pm      46 °F             Passing clouds.                  ↑      56%          30.17 "Hg              10 mi
14             2:51 pm      45 °F                      Sunny.                  ↑      58%          30.17 "Hg              10 mi
15             3:51 pm      45 °F                      Sunny.                  ↑      56%          30.17 "Hg              10 mi
16             4:51 pm      44 °F                      Clear.                  ↑      63%          30.17 "Hg              10 mi
17             5:51 pm      43 °F             Passing clouds.                  ↑      62%          30.16 "Hg              10 mi
18             6:51 pm      42 °F  Light rain. Mostly cloudy.                  ↑      82%          30.16 "Hg               7 mi
19             7:51 pm      42 °F       Light rain. Overcast.                  ↑      79%          30.15 "Hg               7 mi
20             8:51 pm      41 °F  Light rain. Mostly cloudy.                  ↑      86%          30.15 "Hg              10 mi
21             9:51 pm      42 °F              Mostly cloudy.                  ↑      82%          30.14 "Hg              10 mi
22            10:32 pm      42 °F       Light rain. Overcast.                  ↑      85%          30.15 "Hg               8 mi
23            10:51 pm      42 °F       Light rain. Overcast.                  ↑      89%          30.11 "Hg               8 mi
24            11:51 pm      42 °F                        Fog.                  ↑      92%          30.07 "Hg               4 mi
```

Comment: This is a great answer! I really appreciated your help. I have also noticed that there is two tables that correspond to two drop down lists on that web page. The json data you have retrieved are for the first table, the 6-hourly record one. However, I still can't find the data for the second table, the hourly record one. How would you retrieve the data for that one?

Comment: Thanks. I can’t look at the moment, but will look later and get back to you.

Comment: @Isomorphism, check updated solution. Also make sure to accept the solution above.